# Saving double value to core data sometimes save totally wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm updating a core data entity by 2 double values (distance, distanceToClosePoint).
Some of the data get saved with wrong value and the result is a whole mess in my app.

First:

```
- (void)updateTrapDistance:(double)distance trapID:(int)trapID distanceToClosePoint:(double)distanceToClosePoint
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = generateManagedObjectContext();

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trapID.intValue==%i", trapID];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil || fetchedObjects.count == 0) {
    NSLog(@"%s error saving: %@\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);

    return;
}

CoreDataAllTraps *trap = fetchedObjects.firstObject;
[trap setDist:[NSNumber numberWithInt:distance]];
[trap setDist_to_close_point:[NSNumber numberWithInt:distanceToClosePoint]];

if(![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"%s error saving: %@\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo);
    return;
}

NSLog(@"id: %d, distance: %f = %f distanceToClosePoint", trapID, distance, distanceToClosePoint);
NSLog(@"id: %d, dist: %f, dist_to_close_point: %f\n\n", trapID, trap.dist.doubleValue, trap.dist_to_close_point.doubleValue);
```

}

Which prints:

```
2014-02-26 17:40:47.965 Cellular Radar[769:5b0f] id: 32, distance: 130881.349358 = 132445.944382 distanceToClosePoint
2014-02-26 17:40:47.972 Cellular Radar[769:5b0f] id: 32, dist: -191.000000, dist_to_close_point: 1373.000000
```

Then reading it:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getCloseXTraps:(int)numberOfTraps
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = generateManagedObjectContext();

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kCORE_DATA_ALL_TRAPS_ENTITY inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dist_to_close_point.doubleValue > %d", 0];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Specify how the fetched objects should be sorted
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    // Limit the restlus to specific number
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:numberOfTraps];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil || fetchedObjects.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%s error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (CoreDataAllTraps *trap in fetchedObjects) {
            NSLog(@"id: %d, dist_to_close_point: %f, dist: %f", trap.trapID.integerValue, trap.dist_to_close_point.doubleValue, trap.dist.doubleValue);
            Traps *singleTrap = [self convertFromCoreData:trap];
            [newArray addObject:singleTrap];
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
2014-02-26 17:40:54.973 Cellular Radar[769:5b0f] id: 32, dist_to_close_point: 1373.000000, dist: -191.000000
```

Generating NSManagedObjectContext:

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSManagedObjectContext *generateManagedObjectContext()
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    context.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    if ([NSThread isMainThread])    { [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy]; }
    else                            { [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy]; }

    return context;
}
```

I must say, not all of the double values got saved wrong, but some of them and that's enough to make a mess.

What's wrong in here?

Comment: Is it as simple as the fact that you're using `numberWithInt` on doubles?

Comment: Yes.  And probably there was a compiler warning there.

Comment: When you like to convert a numeric value to `NSNumber`, you can now use `@(<variable>)` and it will be automatically converted with the right type

Comment: @HotLicks: There is (by default) no warning if a float is cast to an int.

Comment: @MartinR - But it's not cast to an int, it's being misparameterized as an int.

Comment: @HotLicks: "cast" was the wrong expression. But if a function takes an int parameter then you can call it with a float argument (which will be simply converted to an int). Even with "-Weverything" there is no compiler warning.

Comment: @MartinR - I've never delved into it with named parms, but, eg, with a stringWithFormat parm list, if you call for an int parm and supply a float one the data is totally garbled, in my experience.  And you usually get a warning.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, stringWithFormat (like printf) is special. It takes a "variable argument list", and the compiler compares the format specifiers with the arguments.

Comment: Yep, my bad, it was integer 16.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you have defined the `dist` and `trap.dist_to_close_point` 
attributes in the Core Data model inspector as 
*"Integer 16"*. In that case the Core Data accessor methods (silently) truncate
all values to 16-bit.

For example, if `distance = 130881.349358` then `[NSNumber numberWithInt:distance]`
represents the integer `130881 = 0x1FF41`. Truncating that to 16-bit gives
`0xFF41 = -191`, which is what you observed.

Changing the type to *"Double"* should solve the problem.

You should also use `numberWithDouble:distance` (or `@(distance)`, as Dan suggested) instead of `numberWithInt:distance` for the assignments,
to avoid rounding the value to an integer.

Comment: A little question, what if I want to keep the value as 'integer 16' from double?

Comment: @IdanMoshe: An 16-bit integer can only store (integer) values from -32768 to 32767. So you cannot use it for your values like 130881.349358.